# ORMLite query foreign collection

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I searched a lot but I did not understand how to solve my problem. I have two classes like these:

```
public class A
{
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    int mId;

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false)
    private String mName;

    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = true)
    private Collection<B> mB;
}

public class B
{
    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false)
    private String mIng;

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
    private A mA;
}
```

My purpose is to fill the object A with the the collection of object B.
How can I do? I already have the two DAO object in a class that manage the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can proceed this way :

1)  Create `A` using dao of `A`

2)  Using `A` create `B`

Code :

```
A a = new A(mid , mName);

daoA.create(a); 

for (B b : a.mB) {

   b = new B( mIng , a);
   daoB.create(b);
}
```

Hope this is UseFul...thks

Comment: This is the right answer.  Works perfectly with 1 adjustment: a.mB NOT a.MA.

Answer (score 0):

Class B needs a property of type A for it to have a parent key.

After you´re done with that, i code, the easyest way is to save the instance of A and select it again so the foreignCollection is initialized by ORMLite. Then just by calling add(new B()), new child rows of B will be saved.